# Is there a way to style jquery's datepicker days?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

Let's say I want 5/2/2011 (or any other day) to be a different color than the rest of the days. Is this possible?

This is an example item for a particular day

```
<td class=" " onclick="DP_jQuery_1305738227207.datepicker._selectDay('#datepicker',4,2011, this);return false;"><a class="ui-state-default ui-state-hover" href="#">11</a></td>
```

I don't know if there's any way to override how the datepicker creates ids/classes for each day.

Comment: Probably. It would help if you provide the markup.

Comment: Is it just that day, always and only that day or are there multiple/different days?

Comment: You could use javascript to attach a class to the data wrapper if it matches a date you want to be a different color.

Comment: I have not used this myself, but have you tried the jquery ui themeroller? I've heard that it is very useful to style jquery UI stuff like the calendar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/UBPg5/

---

You can do this by adding a `beforeShowDay` callback

Bind your callback:

```
$("input:text.date").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: SetDayStyle
});
```

Create your function with some static array of bad dates or construct this array somewhere else:

```
var badDates = new Array("5/2/2011");
function SetDayStyle(date) {
    var enabled = true;
    var cssClass = "";

    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1; //0 - 11
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var compare = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

    var toolTip = badDates.indexOf(compare) + " " + compare

    if (badDates.indexOf(compare) >= 0) cssClass = "bad";

    return new Array(enabled, cssClass, toolTip);
}
```

Create your styles

```
.bad { background: red; }
.bad a.ui-state-active { background: red; color: white; }
```

---

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShowDay

> The function takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with [0] equal to true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable, [1] equal to a CSS class name(s) or '' for the default presentation, and [2] an optional popup tooltip for this date. It is called for each day in the datepicker before it is displayed.

Comment: no problem, didn't know that was there until today, but I can see some cool applications

Comment: This solutio worked very well until I change month, when I back to current month, the added class is not there anymore ... any thoughts ?

Comment: yep Diego, same problem here using some kind of function called via beforeShowDay