# How to Apply multiple styles on days

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have to mark three kind of days with different styles: Out_of_window, Free or Unavailable. The unavailable has to be disabled.

[I made a function based on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048342/is-there-a-way-to-style-jquerys-datepicker-days/6048648). And I had to remove the default datepicker class (`ui-state-default`) otherwise I couldn't change the `bg-image`.

Everything work as desired, until I change month. When I get back to original month, the day gets back its orignal class (`ui-state-default`) and I have no more my customized styles according the kind of day.

So, I have the following codes:

```
 var pick_up_out_of_window_dayDates = new Array("2012-12-11","2012-12-12");

 var pick_up_free_dayDates = new Array("2012-12-21","2012-12-22");
```

(as global ones)

```
 function applyDayStyles(date){


var enabled = true;
var cssClass = "";
console.log(date);
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1; //0 - 11
var year = date.getFullYear();
var compare = year  + "-" + month + "-" + day;

var pick_up_out_of_window_day = pick_up_out_of_window_dayDates.indexOf(compare) + " " + compare
var pick_up_free_day = pick_up_free_dayDates.indexOf(compare) + " " + compare

if (pick_up_out_of_window_dayDates.indexOf(compare) >= 0){
    cssClass = "pick_up_out_of_window_dayCalendar";
    console.log(1);
    return  new Array(enabled, cssClass, pick_up_out_of_window_day);

}
else
if (pick_up_free_dayDates.indexOf(compare) >= 0){
    cssClass = "pick_up_free_dayCalendar";
    console.log(2);
    return new Array(enabled, cssClass, pick_up_free_day);
}
else
    return new Array(false, cssClass, date);
```

}

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            minDate: 0,
            beforeShowDay: applyDayStyles
    })
   //{edited}
   // this is un necesssary !
   // $('.pick_up_free_dayCalendar').children().removeClass('ui-state-default').addClass('pick_up_free_dayCalendarIN'); // I Had to add this line to remove the defaukt bg style.

 })
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why would all this be neccessary, it's all about CSS specificity. If you are more specific than the original styles, you can override them, or even better, just change the default stylesheet? I added a specific style, and it seems to work for me -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwg3P/2/)

Comment: For one, you could change the jQuery CSS file, in stead of changing the class. For two, you could provide a jsfiddle, which encourages people to provide you a working solution.

Comment: @EricG . I tried it before, but I could not figure out how to handle two different styles plus disabled ones....

Comment: Like so -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwg3P/9/)

Comment: Are you not familiar with the weights of CSS selectors? Or attribute selectors?

Comment: @adeneo I took off the comment becuase I realized it was pointless ...

so, It worked very well ... I figure out the problem was how I was overriding the default class !!!! I'll post your soulution as answer !!!! many thnx !

Comment: @EricG : Looks like I'm not ... otherwise, I wouldn't need to ask about it ...

Comment: @Diego you didnt mention such a thing in your post, Im just trying to be helpful so you can educate yourself with good practises. Good luck.

Comment: @EriG : Sorry if the facts doesn't sounds polite ...

Answer (score 0):

Just have to override the default class :

```
 .datepicker .pick_up_out_of_window_dayCalendar .ui-state-default {background: red;}
 .datepicker .pick_up_free_dayCalendar .ui-state-default {background: blue;}
```

Thanx to @adeneo (see questions' coments)

http://jsfiddle.net/Cwg3P/2/