# jquery datepicker multiple css classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am looking for a possibility to highlight different dates in jquery's datepicker with different CSS classes.

Simply, append `.green` to `27-10-2013`, `.yellow` to `02-11.2013` and `.red` to `05-11-2013`.
So far, I could not find any solution to use more than one CSS Class with `beforeShowDay` in JQuery's official datepicker.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Unfortunatly its a input field. There is a possibility that you could set the field as display: none, then use jquery to pull the data into a div, from there you could use a regex to change the colors... Its very consuming. Hopefully someone has a better option than mine. GL

Comment: You want to color the cell of the datepicker or the textbox that the datepicker is bound to?

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried so far using beforeShowDay?  I bet that's where you're having problems.

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6048648/1524085 maybe it'll help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is using the answer found in the post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6048648/1524085

I have modified it to fit the OP's needs.

**http://jsfiddle.net/sN9Xy/1/**

**EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/sN9Xy/2/ to show all colors in the same month.**

```
$(".date").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: SetDayStyle
});

var cssDates = [
                ["10/27/2013", "green"], 
                ["2/11/2013", "yellow"], 
                ["5/11/2013", "red"]
               ];

function SetDayStyle(date) {
    var enabled = true;
    var cssClass = "";
    var toolTip = "";

    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1; //0 - 11
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var compare = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

    for (var i = 0; i < cssDates.length; i++) {
        //var toolTip = cssDates[i].indexOf(compare) + " " + compare
        if (cssDates[i].indexOf(compare) >= 0) cssClass = cssDates[i][1];
    }

    return new Array(enabled, cssClass, toolTip);
}
```

Comment: your fiddle only shows .green class, .yellow and .red do not show up.

Comment: Tested in chrome, firefox and ie on windows, and chrome and firefox on mac. I see all three colors on all the dates. Maybe i misunderstood?

Comment: i added another fiddle for all the 3 colors in the same month.

Comment: sorry, only see `10/27/2013` as `green` (in Firefox, Chrome and IE). `2/11/2013` and `5/11/2013` still have default color.

Answer (score 0):

Keith Wood's datepick.

```
$('a[title="Select Wednesday, Oct 16, 2013"]').addClass("red");
```

Format your dates to `Select Wednesday, Oct 16, 2013` format and use it in the selector.

Answer (score 0):

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZUZSH/1/ , got the idea from here http://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-add-class

```
var redDays = [[10, 19, 2013],[10, 21, 2013]];
var greenDays = [[10,20, 2013],[10, 22, 2013]];
$("#cal").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: myDays})
function myDays(date) {
for (i = 0; i < redDays.length; i++) {
if (date.getMonth() == redDays[i][0] - 1
&& date.getDate() == redDays[i][1]
&& date.getFullYear() == redDays[i][2]) {
return [true, 'red' ];
}
}

for (i = 0; i < greenDays.length; i++) {
if (date.getMonth() == greenDays[i][0] - 1
&& date.getDate() == greenDays[i][1]
&& date.getFullYear() == greenDays[i][2]) {
return [true, 'green' ];
}
}
return [true, ''];    
}
```